# New MySQL Server slower than the old

Tags: mysql, performance, server, percona

In summary, I have a new mysql server that is running slower than the one it is replacing. I'm trying to determine if this is due to the almost non-existent load on the new server while I'm testing it (IE: Query optimizer doesn't know to do). I just don't want to flip the switch on this thing and our apps time out and die.

Now for the details...both are MySQL (Percona) 5.5 servers.
The "old" server is an Xeon 8c/16t, 128GB ram, 6x SAS 15k RAID10 box.
The "new" server is a dual Xeon, 16c/32t, 256GB ram, 6x SSD RAID 10 box.

The old server is running debian, the new Ubuntu.
That is pretty much the only non-hardware difference between the two.
Both are using the EXACT same my.cnf configuration.
The MySQL database is strictly INNODB.

I have the "new" server setup as a slave to the "old" for testing.
However, a majority of select queries are 2-10x slower when executed on the new, substantially faster hardware. Even after the buffer pool has had time to load, subsequent query runs are still much slower. It's almost like the new server won't cache anything, despite identical configs.

EXPLAIN doesn't always show the same execution plan.
If I use FORCE INDEX on the new box to get the correct plan, that usually helps but not always.

For the heck of it, below is the tweaked portion of the my.cnf currently on each box. The current live server (old) is about 600 Selects/sec, 150 InsertUpdates/sec. Occasionally spiking to ~double that volume.

```
key_buffer              = 128M
max_allowed_packet      = 16M
thread_stack            = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 8
max_connections         = 350 
read_rnd_buffer_size    = 2M
read_buffer_size        = 1M
sort_buffer_size        = 2M
join_buffer_size        = 3M 
bulk_insert_buffer_size = 8M
table_open_cache        = 4096
table_definition_cache  = 2048 
thread_cache_size       = 32
max_heap_table_size     = 64M 
tmp_table_size          = 64M 
query_cache_limit       = 4M
query_cache_size        = 128M

default-storage-engine  = innodb
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 81920M
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 20M
innodb_buffer_pool_instances = 4 
innodb_log_file_size    = 256M  
innodb_log_buffer_size  = 4M 
innodb_thread_concurrency = 12
innodb_flush_method     = O_DIRECT  
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2  
innodb_file_format      = barracuda
innodb_support_xa       = 0         
innodb_file_per_table   = true
innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct=75 
innodb_read_io_threads  = 8
innodb_write_io_threads = 8
innodb_io_capacity      = 500
```

Thank you in advance for any assistance.

----EDIT: Sample Query & Explain---

Here is one of the nastier queries (picked on purpose), making use of a union and joins. It is looking at RFID data in two tables and consolidating it.

Log_RFID_WebService has ~5 million rows.
Log_RFID_Zonal has ~2 million rows.

Old Server Execution Time (3 runs): .110, .074, .074

New Server Execution Time (3 runs): .234, .250, .249

Again, seems like a caching issue of some kind...or the temp tables are much slower on the new server...which still wouldn't make sense to me

```
SELECT 
sql_calc_found_rows 
Q.*,D.MktDlrCode,GetLastOrder(Q.CustId,D.StoreId,Q.Timestamp) As       LastOrder
FROM 
((SELECT
Zonal.ID,Zonal.CustId,Zonal.SID,'' As  Lane,Zonal.RFIDtag,ANT.Antenna,ANT.Location,ANT.Direction,Timestamp,DATE_FORMAT(Timestamp,'%c/%d/%y %l:%i:%s %p') As DateTimestamp
FROM Portal.Log_RFID_Zonal As Zonal 
INNER JOIN Portal.Log_RFID_Antennas As ANT ON
ANT.Antenna=Zonal.LocationCode AND
ANT.SID=Zonal.SID AND
ANT.IgnoreFlag=0
WHERE
Zonal.Timestamp>=STR_TO_DATE('08/01/2015','%m/%d/%Y') AND
Zonal.Timestamp<DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE('08/01/2015','%m/%d/%Y'), INTERVAL 1     day)
ORDER BY Zonal.Timestamp DESC
)
UNION
(SELECT
RFID.ID,RFID.CustId,RFID.SID,RFID.Lane,RFID.RFIDtag,ANT.Antenna,ANT.Location,ANT.Direction,Timestamp,DATE_FORMAT(Timestamp,'%c/%d/%y %l:%i:%s %p') As DateTimestamp
FROM Portal.Log_RFID_WebService As RFID 
INNER JOIN Portal.Log_RFID_Antennas As ANT ON
ANT.Antenna=RFID.LocationCode AND
ANT.SID=RFID.SID AND
ANT.IgnoreFlag=0 
WHERE
RFID.Timestamp>=STR_TO_DATE('08/01/2015','%m/%d/%Y') AND
RFID.Timestamp<DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE('08/01/2015','%m/%d/%Y'), INTERVAL 1 day)
ORDER BY RFID.Timestamp DESC
)
ORDER BY
Timestamp DESC
) As Q
INNER JOIN Stores As D ON
D.StoreId=Q.SID AND
D.ReportFlag=1
LIMIT 0,25;
```

The explain is the same on both servers for this particular query:

```
Id SelType      Table        Type    Key       Rows    Extra
1 PRIMARY      <derived>    ALL               300     Using where;Using Index
1 PRIMARY      D            ref     StoreId   1       Using Where
2 DERIVED      Zonal        range   ix1       6368    Using where
2 DERIVED      ANT          eq_ref  PRIMARY   1       Using where
3 UNION        RFID         range   ix1       938     Using where
3 UNION        ANT          eq_ref  PRIMARY   1       Using where
  UNION RESULT              ALL               0       Using filesort
```

Comment: Most interesting. Can you add a sample query and it's explain. Also the result of a trivial query such as select 1; ? By the way how are you connecting to the servers? The client software and the machines; are they the same?

Comment: I agree that the slowdown does not make sense.  Let's take a close look at a couple of `SELECTs` that are running noticeably slower.  Please include `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and a hint of table size.

Comment: @e4c5: Yes, both servers are right next to each other on the same switch. I have executed the queries from both WorkBench and the MySQL console directly, the results where the same. The queries are rather elaborate, let me see if I can get something that isn't 100 lines long posted up in the original post.

Comment: Just select id from table_name where id = something would be sufficient. Your musql workbench and console are both on a machine that is different from the two servers I presume.

Comment: @e4c5: If I do a simple SELECT id FROM Log_RFID_WebService WHERE id=x; I get a 0.00 execution time on the Old and 0.031 on the New. The table has ~5 million rows, ID is the primary key.   I also added some information with one of the uglier queries (shorter though at least). Thank you both for your help!

Comment: I should also mention the problem is not isolated to this query or tables, it seems fairly consistent. Now if I do a HUGE select resulting in a massive temp table...the new server usually wins out. It's primarily the more common "smaller" queries giving me grief.

Comment: What sort of interface are the SSD's using? Are they using SAS?

Comment: Yes, Enterprise SAS drives on a PERC controller...sorry don't remember which one but it was the best Dell offered. Filesystem benchmarks seem fine.

Comment: Hang on a second, this is running as a slave right? What's the bet that the difference in time is due to the slave lag? Can you disable the replication, make the new server it's own master and try the query.

Comment: Yes the new server is presently running as a slave. So you're saying that queries against historical data would be lagged? I thought slave lag pertained only to the "freshness" of the data if you will. I can change it to a master, but it may not be possible until this evening.

Comment: Is the MySQL version the same on both machines?

Comment: yes, both are Percona 5.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oddly enough, disabling hyper-threading on the new server seemed to resolve the issue. Never would have guessed that would have had an impact in low load situations.